# How to monitor changes in security certificates?

Tags: certificate, trusted-root-certificates

We all like the pseudo-safety granted us by security certificates. It's beneficial in many ways, I'm not saying the contrary. However, I have a concern about my information privacy at my workplace. Here is the situation :

- My employer use to allow people going on social media websites (Facebook, and forums mostly.)
- One day, the web filter started blocking the access to these websites, unless you have a certificate installed.
- "Conveniently", that same day they installed a certificate (without our knowledge) that allows you to connect to these websites.
- Now, when you try to access these websites, you see the little green lock saying it's "safe", it has a certificate (yay!)

However, if you look at the certificate, it's not, for example, Facebook's, it's my employer. Doing this, if I'm not mistaken, they force any data through their servers in a way that they can sniff whatever they want. I disabled the certificates, so now I can't go on these websites, and I'm fine with that, I'm going there to work, not to chat with people.

**The question**: Is there a way I can monitor changes in certificates in a way that I wouldn't need to check each and every certificates when I'm browsing to see if they re-enabled them?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might benefit from [Perspectives](http://perspectives-project.org/) or possibly [Convergence](http://convergence.io/).

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon, and as far as I can tell these links are only tangentially related to the question.